# Generating test run/result for manual testing from Cucumber Feature files

Tags: cucumber

For my simple mobile app, I have started migrating my test cases from a Google Doc into cucumber feature files. I have yet to automate the steps, so there are all manual cases.

Is there a way for me to generate a test run document/text/html from these cucumber feature files, and then when I manually go through the test cases, I can mark each one as pass/fail.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are several tools and plugins available that can help you generate a test run document from Cucumber feature files. Here are a few options:

1. Cucumber Reports Plugin: This plugin generates HTML reports from Cucumber JSON files. You can run your manual tests and generate a JSON file using the Cucumber command line interface, and then use the plugin to convert the JSON file into an HTML report. The report includes a summary of the test results, as well as details for each feature and scenario. You can mark each scenario as pass/fail by editing the JSON file before generating the report. More information about the plugin can be found here: https://github.com/jenkinsci/cucumber-reports-plugin
2. Cucumber HTML Reports: This tool also generates HTML reports from Cucumber JSON files, but it includes more customization options than the Cucumber Reports Plugin. You can add logos, custom stylesheets, and other elements to the report, as well as mark each scenario as pass/fail. The tool can be downloaded from here: https://github.com/masterthought/cucumber-reporting
3. Cucumber-JVM HTML Reporter: This is another HTML report generator for Cucumber tests. It can generate reports from both JSON and XML files, and includes options for customizing the report layout and colors. You can mark each scenario as pass/fail by editing the source file before generating the report. More information about the tool can be found here: https://github.com/damianszczepanik/cucumber-reporting

Once you have generated a test run document, you can use it to keep track of your manual test results. You can mark each scenario as pass/fail, and include any notes or comments about the test. This can be a useful way to keep track of your testing progress, and to ensure that all scenarios have been tested thoroughly.